# Android Horizontal RecyclerView with dynamic amount of rows and columns

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, uicollectionview, android-gridview, horizontal-recyclerview

I need to create a Horizontal RecyclerView with dynamic rows and columns, and every cell has the same width, but different height. Which means column width should be consistent and row height is dynamic.

I've tried implementing this behavior with FlexBoxLayoutManager, StaggeredGridLayoutManager, GridLayoutManager. Also attempted with GridView but then realized it's not supported with horizontal scroll.

I'm trying to find something that is similar to UICollectionView in iOS.

As seen in the photo, columns are unlimited, and number of cells per column depends on the height of the cells. So each column has a different number of cells.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`FlexBoxLayoutManager` supports what you're trying to achieve.

You want to use it within a `RecyclerView` have a look at `FlexDirection`

https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout#flexboxlayoutmanager-within-recyclerview

Comment: As mentioned, I've tried this bus still don't understand how to wrap children like in the photo